# How to declare Polymer property for element's flex-direction

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In the following code, I'm trying to declare a property in a Polymer element that allows the user to choose the element's `flex-direction`, but it's not working. Can someone provide a working example?

```
Polymer({
    is: 'container-element',
    properties: {
        flexDirection: {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            computed: '_changeFlexDirection(dir)'
        }
    },
    _changeFlexDirection: function(dir){
        var el = document.getElementsByTagName('container-element')[0];
        return el.style.flexDirection = "column";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were trying to implement a [simple observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#simple-observers), but you unintentionally used a computed property. Also, using `document.getElementsByTagName()` to get a reference to the element's own styles is unnecessary (and would be buggy if multiple instances of the element are in the document), as you could simply do that with `this.style`. Here's your code corrected:

```
properties: {
  flexDirection: {
    type: String,
    observer: '_flexDirChanged'
  }
},
_flexDirChanged: function(flexDirection) {
  this.style.flexDirection = flexDirection;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <x-foo flex-direction="row"></x-foo>
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      </style>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties: {
            flexDirection: {
              type: String,
              observer: '_flexDirChanged'
            }
          },
          _flexDirChanged: function(flexDirection) {
            this.style.flexDirection = flexDirection;
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

You could also expose a [CSS property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-properties) that users could override. This example has a default `flex-direction` of `column`, and exposes `--x-foo-flex-direction` to override the default in a `custom-style`.

```
// index.html
<style is="custom-style">
  .row {
    --x-foo-flex-direction: row;
  }
</style>
<x-foo class="row"></x-foo>

// x-foo.html
<style>
  :host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: var(--x-foo-flex-direction, column);
  }
</style>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    .flexcol {
      --x-foo-flex-direction: row;
    }
  </style>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <x-foo class="flexcol"></x-foo>
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: var(--x-foo-flex-direction, column);
        }
      </style>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```